# Change property of a single child from parent

Tags: lightning-web-components

I want to hide a certain section on the child component according to some logic that happens on the parent component.

So I exposed a method on the child with the @api decorator and I called it from the parent, but instead of hiding just a single section, it hides all of them.

```
----parent.html----
<template>
        <template if:true={showFeatures}>
                <template for:each={features} for:item='feature'>
                    <c-child label={feature.label} key={feature.label} ></c-child>
                </template>
        </template>
</template>

----parent.js----

import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    @track showFeatures = true;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.hideSectionOnChild(); //calling child method 
    }
    
    hideSectionOnChild(){
        this.template.querySelector("c-child").hideSection();
    }
    

    get features() {
        return [
            {
                label: 'section 1',
                icon: 'utility:edit',
            },
            {
                label: 'section 2',
                icon: 'utility:refresh',
            },
            {
                label: 'section 3',
                icon: 'utility:brush',
            },
        ];
    }
}

----child.html----

<template>
    <template if:true={section1}>
        {label} + {myValue} <br>
    </template>
    <template if:true={section2}>
        {label} + {myValue} <br>
    </template>
    <template if:true={section3}>
        {label} + {myValue} <br>
    </template>      
      
</template>

----child.js----

import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Child extends LightningElement {
    @api label = '';
    @api myValue;
    @api section1=false
    @api section2=false
    @api section3=false

    connectedCallback(){
        if(this.label == 'section 1'){
            this.section1 = true;
        }
        if(this.label == 'section 2'){
            this.section2 = true;
        }
        if(this.label == 'section 3'){
            this.section3 = true;
        }               
    }

    @api hideSection(){
        this.section2 = false;
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems.

@api variables are read-only in a component. The sectionX Boolean values should be just normal values:

```
section1 = false;
section2 = false;
section3 = false;
```

---

The querySelector fails when I tried it. I had to add an asynchronous update to make sure it doesn't fail:

```
hideSectionOnChild() {
  setTimeout(() => this.template.querySelector("c-child").hideSection());
}
```

---

All the section code is the same here, so you can't really tell if it changed anyways. Aside from that, the first child's second section is already hidden, so perhaps not the best example to work with.

Try:

```
@api hideSection() {
  this.section1 = false;
}
```

---

I'm not entirely sure what you hope to accomplish with your design, but you may need to change your model.

I created a [working version](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/6tH0wrXckfGIojseLdtp) for you to start from.